# Wrap unwrapped textNode using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML structure like this:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <a href="#">tempor</a> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
```

I need to get the text inside the div wrapped in `<p>` tag. I'm using the code below:

```
$('.col-md-6').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).each(function() {
    this.nodeValue = $.trim(this.nodeValue);
}).wrap('<p></p>');
```

Which works fine IF there is no link (`<a>`) inside the text. The output with my jQuery code would be:

```html
<div class="col-md-6"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod </p><a href="#">tempor</a><p> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
```

This is my desired result:

```html
<div class="col-md-6"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <a href="#">tempor</a> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: just use `$('.col-md-6').html('<p>' + $('.col-md-6').html() + '</p>')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `html()` and `contents()`

```js
$('.col-md-6').html(function() {
  return $('<p/>').html($(this).contents())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <a href="#">tempor</a> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
```

For multiple `.col-md-6` with `textNode`

```js
$('.col-md-6').each(function() {
  $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).siblings().addBack().wrapAll('<p></p>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <a href="#">tempor</a> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>

<div class="col-md-6"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <a href="#">tempor</a> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p></div>

<div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <a href="#">tempor</a> incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that works great, however - it will wrap ALL .col-md-6 contents in paragraphs. In my code, I'm checking if it's a plain text. Do you know how to implement this check in your solution?

Comment: great solution! Thanks for your help.